# Web-scraping jquery loaded page

Tags: html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to web-scrape the below page. I cant see the content for the table in the beautified object. I assume this is because the information is loaded there using jQuery? Is there a way around this?

```
lith=requests.get('https://www.benchmarkminerals.com/lithium-prices/')
    
lithium_soup=bs4.BeautifulSoup(lith.content, 'html.parser')


lithium_table= lithium_soup.find('table', {'id':'lithium-index_summary'})

lithium_table
```

Returned:

```
<table class="price-index_summary" id="lithium-index_summary"></table>
```

I get the table but none of the table data in the lithium_table? Can someone please assist?

[image: This is what the table should contain]

This is the html code from inspecting the website

[image: HTML code on website]

Answer (score 0):

The data comes from a different endpoint and is dynamically rendered. `bs4` won't see that in the source `HTML`.

To get the table data, use this:

```py
import json

import requests

url = "https://www.benchmarkminerals.com/wp-json/benchmark/v1/lithium-index_summary"
data = requests.get(url).json()
print(json.dumps(data, indent=2))
```

Output:

```json
{
  "lithium": {
    "month": "7.8",
    "yearOnYear": "181.2",
    "yearToDate": "140.6",
    "today": "1,110.8",
    "last": "1,030.9"
  },
  "carbonate": {
    "month": "8.0",
    "yearOnYear": "182.0",
    "yearToDate": "138.9",
    "today": "1,156.4",
    "last": "1,070.4"
  },
  "hydroxide": {
    "month": "7.2",
    "yearOnYear": "177.6",
    "yearToDate": "151.4",
    "today": "1,025.6",
    "last": "957.1"
  }
}
```

To rebuild the table, import `pandas` and create a `DataFrame`.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data).T
print(df)
```

Output:

```
          month yearOnYear yearToDate    today     last
lithium     7.8      181.2      140.6  1,110.8  1,030.9
carbonate   8.0      182.0      138.9  1,156.4  1,070.4
hydroxide   7.2      177.6      151.4  1,025.6    957.1
```

Comment: How did you get that URL? Did you use Chrome Dev Tools? I am using FireFox and want to see how to get that URL in the future in case I run into the same problem on other websites

Comment: Yes, I've used Dev Tools. It doesn't really matter which browser you use.

Comment: Which tab on Dev Tools do you see the URL under? Thanks for your assistance